# What's the reliable way to know php command line script path?

Tags: php, command-line

I have a file system structure with symlinks, something like this:

```
folder123
    index.php
    config.php -> symlink to shared/config.php
shared
    config.php
```

I run index.php on command line, index.php includes config.php, which is symlink to a file in some other folder.

How can I know index.php file path from the config.php script? The required result is "folder123" (well the full path of it), not "shared". So, I cannot use __FILE__.

This works on scripts, ran by browser (at least in my case, it is the same as folder123 - the base dir):

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']
```

I need something for the command-line too.

It looks like

```
$_SERVER['PWD']
```

is something what I need, but it's not documented, so I don't find it a reliable way. Also, you need to combile it with SCRIPT_FILENAME to get the required results - PWD shows directory, from which the script was run, not it's full path.

getcwd looks promising, but it can be changed by chdir - I'll use that if I don't find some better alternative.

Comment: Have you tried getcwd() method?

Comment: It works, but, as I mentioned, can be changed by chdir function. I just thought there might be some more reliable way.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a way to determine what file included a file, but you can get the name of the running program (`index.php` in this case) with `$argv[0]`, or possibly `$_SERVER['argv'][0]` if the former is not available.

```
//config.php
//running path
$path = dirname(realpath($argv[0]));
```

Comment: Inside a function, you will need to use `global $argv;` before you reference it. `$_SERVER` is a superglobal, so you can just use it inside a function. http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php

Answer (score -3):

If you use PHP 5.3 or higher you can use

```
$path = __DIR__;
```

instead.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

Comment: This would return `shared`, not `folder123`